# What is the result of calling return in a non-void function after calling a function returning int?

Tags: c, return, return-value

**UPDATE 2018: This was an old question I wrote with reduced understanding of C. Please refrain from downvoting.**

---

When I use the following code:

```
int mytest(void);
int main(void)
{
   mytest();
   return;
}
int mytest(void)
{
   return 3;
}
```

What is the return value of `main`? I understand this is

- undefined behavior
- might produce an error

> Edit: large comment: **I know this is undefined behavior.** Logically, what return value will be produced?
>
> Edit 2: **Sample: http://ideone.com/fAxnNn**

Comment: `return` wirhout an expression is not permitted in a function returning a non-void.

Comment: @abelenky IDEONE should never be used for a code checking. If you have a code, check it yourself and if you are sure that your code is OK, show it with IDEONE. But never use IDEONE to check your code. [Check this simple example](http://ideone.com/DRTOi5). You do realize that initializer element is not constant. More over, as far as I know IDEONE use only 32 BIT compiler (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: Short answer: it depends on the compiler / settings.  That's what undefined behavior means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is you don't seem to understand what [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) means.

When you invoke undefined behavior, anything can happen.  Your program can crash, it can generate unexpected results, or it can appear to work correctly.  Making a seeming unrelated change, such as adding an unused variable or an extra call to `printf`, can change how undefined behavior manifests itself.

This also means that two different compilers can generate different results for the same code, or that one compiler with two different optimization settings can generate different results.

I'll give you an example.  I compiled your original code on a CentOS 5.10 with gcc 4.1.2.  First I compiled without any optimization:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -o /tmp/x1 /tmp/x1.c
```

I ran the resulting code and then ran `echo $?`.  The latter prints the exit code of the previous process (i.e. the return value of `main`).  The result:

```
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ /tmp/x1
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ echo $?
3
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$
```

Now I'll compile the same code on a Windows 7 machine under Visual Studio 2010:

```
cl x1.c
```

If I run this and then `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` to print the return code, I get this:

```
C:\Users\dbush\Documents>x1

C:\Users\dbush\Documents>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0

C:\Users\dbush\Documents>
```

As you can see, gcc and MSVC generate different results for the same code.  In one case it returns 3 while in the other case it return 0.

Now let's play around with optimization.  I compiled the same code on the same CentOS machine with the same version of gcc, but with optimization turned on:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -o /tmp/x1 /tmp/x1.c -O3
```

I then ran this twice. I then got the following result:

```
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ /tmp/x1
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ echo $?
68
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ /tmp/x1
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ echo $?
36
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$
```

So not only do I get different results when running with different optimization settings, I get different results running the **same program multiple times**.  That's what can happen with undefined behavior.

So to answer your question "what return value will be produced", the answer is it depends because you invoked undefined behavior.  You can't reliably predict what will happen.

EDIT:

More examples with your updated code.

On gcc with no optimizations:

```
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ /tmp/x1
mytest2 = 3
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ echo $?
12
```

On gcc with optimization `-O3`:

```
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ /tmp/x1
mytest2 = -1078711820
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ echo $?
22
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ /tmp/x1
mytest2 = -1077511916
[dbush@db-centos tmp]$ echo $?
22
```

On MSVC with no optimizations:

```
C:\Users\dbush\Documents>x1
mytest2 = 3

C:\Users\dbush\Documents>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0

C:\Users\dbush\Documents>
```

On MSVC with optimization `/Ox`:

```
C:\Users\dbush\Documents>x1
mytest2 = 1

C:\Users\dbush\Documents>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0

C:\Users\dbush\Documents>
```

So again, no guarantees.

Comment: I'll award you the bounty for the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a *desired* behaviour, though not *explicitly* mentioned as undefined behaviour. This is a "Constraints violation".

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.8.6.4

> [...] A `return` statement without an expression shall only appear in a function
>   whose return type is `void`.

and, from chapter §5.1.1.3, *Diagnostics*,

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in
>   an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit
>   contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly
>   specified as undefined or implementation-defined. [....]

In this case, compiler proceeds to generate the executable code, so, yes, executing this binary invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Bottom line, for `main()` which is expected to return an `int` should not have a `return` statement without an expression. Refrain from writing code like that.

---

<sup>*[Note: [As per this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/WNVXRSCqrGU), there's a strong notion that this is undefined behaviour, but still, there's no **explicit** mention in the standard.]*</sup>

Comment: I may have worded my question wrong, but **what is the return value of `main` _likely_ to be in this case?**

Comment: @MarkYisri The problem here is, execution of this program (if a compiler generates a binary, at all) invokes UB, so thing is guranteed.

Answer (score 0):

The program as shown is not legal C.  The use of `return;` in a non-void function like that is a *constraint violation*, and your compiler is required to complain.  Usually, that will be an error, but a compiler is allowed to produce a program - but the standard obviously does not make any requirements on the behaviour of such a program.  Therefore its behaviour is not defined (technically, this is slightly different from Undefined Behaviour, as it's not something explicitly specified as "*undefined*" in the standard).

There's no point asking questions like, "*What happens when I cause Undefined Behaviour?*" because the answer is always, "*Anything*."

As an aside, you are allowed to **omit** a return statement (i.e. to run off the end of the function) *as long as your program does not use the return value*.  If the program uses the return value, then the behaviour is Undefined (not merely unspecified).  In particular, running off the end of `main()` is legal.  Although there's no rationale for allowing functions with no `return` but not those with an explicit void `return`, I presume it's due to the logical undecidability of whether a function's end is reachable (it's a case of the Halting Problem).

Of particular interest in this case is that the function in question is `main()`.  Options available to the compiler (in addition to emitting the required diagnostic) include (but are not limited to):

- Terminate compilation
- Optimise out `return;` as the last statement in a function, and treat it the same as `main()` with no return statement
- Return an uninitialized value (which might be a signalling value on architectures that support them, or it might be a recently-used stack value, or something else altogether)

Comment: I'd be interested if you can quote something related to this. Thanks.

Comment: The standard makes no requirements on programs that are not well-formed - a compiler should normally reject such inputs with a suitable error message.  "*A `return` statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is `void`*" - that "**shall**" absolves the compiler from producing any program at all.

Comment: That said, you're allowed to omit the `return` from `main()` (and only from `main()`), so a compiler might choose to treat a void return as equivalent.  But unless it documents that, we can't reason about it here!

Comment: OK, I had a quick look at the draft of the standard and you're correct. I've amended my answer to include the chain of reference. :)

Comment: @TobySpeight Your comments helps more than the whole Answer you provide. This means that your Comments are actually an Answer and your Answer is no more than a Comment.

Comment: I may have worded my question wrong, but **what is the return value of `main` _likely_ to be in this case?**

Comment: The C standard does not talk about "well-formed" programs. Perhaps you're thinking of C++? A `return;` with no expression in a non-`void` function is a *constraint violation*, and a conforming implementation is required to issue a diagnostic. (That diagnostic may be a non-fatal warning; in that case it's not 100% clear whether the behavior of the resulting program is undefined.) The rule that a non-`void` function may not have a `return;` with no expression was added in C99.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more precise in my terminology.  Your comment is much clearer than my answer; I'll incorporate most of it as an edit -unless you want to answer for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments (not from the question), I understood that the main aim is to find what is returned by main by doing `return;`. I hope I am going in right direction.

**First thing** is few compiler allow writing just `return;` and some give a warning and a few compiler give implicitly add `return 0;` if nothing is returned by main.

**Second thing** returning 0 signifies successful execution of the program and if returning anything else will mean some runtime error(At least your environment thinks that way).

Now coming to your doubt: what is implicitly returned by main by writing `return;`. I checked with the tool you are using [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) and C (gcc-5.1).

With `return;` it gave

```
Runtime error   time: 0 memory: 2164 signal:-1
```

With `return 0;` it gave

```
Success time: 0 memory: 2164 signal:0
```

With `return 1;` it again gave

```
Runtime error   time: 0 memory: 2164 signal:-1
```

In this signal signifies the returned value from `main`

If you use the terminal to run your program, you can use `echo $?` to get the returned value.

So now you can observe yourself that `return;` and `return 1;` give the same output (the implicit value returned can be garbage too). Still, we cannot guarantee this but now you have all the tools you need to find out.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Can you try it with the new updated code

Comment: @MarkYisri sorry, this is not a discussion forum.  You are welcome to ask new questions, but it's not fair to the people who answered you to change your question.