# Is running a binary generated from a code with "constraint violation" actually undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Reference: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41148654/2173917)

Context: A `return` statement at the end of `main()` with no expression, like

```
 return;
```

As I read the standard, it appears to be  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and so I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41148748/2173917).

However, [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41149104/2173917) says, it's not UB.

Where did I go wrong reading or understanding the standard *language*?

---

<sup>Note: I have seen [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/WNVXRSCqrGU) already, but I cannot conclude.</sup>

Comment: Its constraint violation, not an undefined behavior. Statement `return;` just return a `void` type, while `main` expects its return type to be `int`.

Comment: And in the case of a constraint violation, the compiler must diagnose (produce a message) for it. If the compiler then proceeds to produce output anyway, the standard has nothing to say about what the output program does, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @haccks Right sir, that is why I also referred to chapter 4, where exactly i'm puzzled.

Comment: I tend to close this as being a duplicate to the referenced question ...

Comment: @alk emm.. why is that sir? I'm not asking the same, all I'm looking for an alternate wordings for the quoted spec in my answer to either validate or invalidate my answer under the other question, that's all. If I can improve this question in any way, please let me know.

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer in the other thread using the comments provided here (thanks to haccks and @R.. for that). A quick review, anyone?

Comment: @SouravGhosh; I would say that it would be better if you seek help from [Keith Thompson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) in this matter. He could help better.

Comment: @haccks I'd try to get in touch with him via chat, thanks.

Comment: The [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41149104/2173917), saying it's not UB, was deleted by its owner.

Comment: I think the context and the title could get a different answer: Title: definitive "NO, not UB". Context: I'm guessing UB, as with KeithThompson.

Comment: I was seriously tempted to post two answers, one "Yes" and one "No", with a lengthy explanation for each.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume this context:

```
int main(void) {
    return;
}
```

and a hosted implementation.

Note that `void main()` is not strictly forbidden (an implementation is permitted to permit it), and `return;` would be perfectly valid within such a definition of `main`.

First off, this `return;` is clearly a constraint violation.  It violates [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.8.6.4p1:

> A **`return`** statement without an expression shall only appear in a function whose return type is **`void`**.

(It was not a constraint violation in C90; that was changed in C99.)

The standard requires a compiler to issue at least one diagnostic for any program containing a violation of a constraint or syntax rule.  Once it's done so, it can then proceed to generate an executable (if the diagnostic is a non-fatal warning).

It's not clear whether there's a general rule that programs with constraint violations have undefined behavior. The standard doesn't say so explicitly. It defines a "constraint" as a

> restriction, either syntactic or semantic, by which the exposition of language elements is to be interpreted

My own interpretation is that if a constraint is violated, there is no valid interpretation, and thus the behavior is undefined, but there are some who disagree. I'd like to see an explicit statement to this effect in a future standard.

I believe the wording of the C Standard is genuinely ambiguous on this point.

Without such a general rule, it's not clear that the behavior is undefined. After stating the constraint that this code violates, the standard goes on to define the semantics of the `return` statement:

> A **`return`** statement terminates execution of the current function
>   and returns control to its caller.

That description could still make sense even in the presence of this constraint violation. It's reasonable to assume, though it's not quite stated, that `return;` is equivalent to reaching the closing `}`, which is equivalent to `return 0;` (this is a special-case rule for `main`; N1570 5.1.2.2.3).

On the other hand, it's not 100% clear that the description is unambiguous. The argument that `return;` is equivalent to reaching the closing `}` is particularly weak. So even in the absence of a general rule, one could argue that the behavior is undefined by omission (there's no definition of the behavior).

The `return;` is clearly a constraint violation, and *in my opinion* it has undefined behavior if the implementation produces an executable. Of course a conforming compiler is also permitted to reject the program altogether; in that case, it has no behavior at all.

Bottom line: It's much *much* ***much*** easier to change the `return;` to `return 0;` than to answer this question.

I encourage other language lawyers to refute this answer. I've made enough internally inconsistent arguments here that it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Regarding the constraint violation and undefined behavior, I'd like to bring this quote to your attention: "If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears **outside of a constraint** or runtime constraint
is violated, the behavior is undefined. [..]" (§ 4/2 N1570) From that I'd say a constraint violation is not UB. But continuing the quote: "[..] Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or by **the omission of any explicit definition of behavior**". Thus I'd say that `return;` is UB.

Comment: @DanielJour: I think I agree with your conclusion, but I'm not 100% sure. As I said in my answer, the standard *does* define the behavior of `return;`. The question is whether that definition still applies when the `return;` is in a non-`void` function. I believe the Standard is ambiguous on this point.

Comment: I am also not sure that a constraint violation is always UB, but in this particular case I would say (contradicting my comment on OP's post) that the *shall* in  *A return statement without an expression **shall** only appear in a function whose return type is void.*, makes the behavior undefined. As standard says: *If a **‘‘shall’’** or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears **outside of a constraint** or runtime constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @haccks: That **shall** is in a constraint.

Comment: @KeithThompson; To me it seems out of constraint.

Comment: @haccks: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.8.6.4. The "shall"s in question are in paragraph 1, which is directly under a "Constraints" header. The "Semantics" section starts with paragraph 2.

Comment: @KeithThompson; Since `return;` statement appeared in a function (`main`) whose return type is `int` and not `void`, the "shall" requirement appears to be outside of the constraint.

Comment: @haccks: I'm starting to wonder if we're looking at the same document. The `return` statement is specified in N1570 6.8.6.4. There are exactly two occurrences of the word **shall** in that subsection. Both are in paragraph 1, which is the entirety of the **Constraints** section. How is that outside of the constraint?

Comment: @KeithThompson; I think I misunderstood it. But I am still not sure when constraint violation invoke UB and when not.

Comment: @haccks: A constraint violation permits the compiler to reject the program altogether. In that case, there is no behavior, defined or otherwise. But if an implementation diagnoses a constraint violation with a non-fatal warning and then generates an executable, it's not clear whether the behavior is necessarily undefined. I think the standard is unclear on this point. If the standard doesn't define the behavior, then the behavior is undefined.

Comment: In other cases .. well, the definition of a "constraint" is a "restriction, either syntactic or semantic, by which the exposition of language elements is
to be interpreted". If a constraint is violated, one could argue that there is no way to interpret the language elements. (I personally think that the standard *should* say that the behavior is undefined if a constraint is violated, but I'm not sure that it actually does.)

Comment: @KeithThompson; Hope next revision of C standard will look into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the title:

> Is running a binary generated from a code with “constraint violation” actually undefined behaviour?

I say **no** because of the definition of undefined behaviour in the standard, emphasis mine:

> If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears **outside of a
>   constraint** or runtime constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.
>   Undefined behavior **is otherwise indicated** in this International Standard
>   by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or by the omission of any explicit
>   definition of behavior. There is no difference in emphasis among
>   these three; they all describe ‘‘behavior that is undefined’’
>
> § 4/2

Assuming that violating a constraint means breaking a "shall" or "shall not" requirement that is *inside* a section marked as "constraint" and it is not otherwise indicated that the violation leads to UB.

As per the context case I agree with Keith Thompson's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The standard doesn't define the behaviour of code containing a constraint violation. Therefore the behaviour is undefined.

Saying that code containing a constraint violation is well-defined is tantamount to saying that all constraints in the Standard can be ignored, which is absurd.

Comment: Hmm, you mean that "or" part of the quote in my answer?

Comment: I like your conclusion, and it's plausible that that's the intent, but I'm not convinced it follows from the wording of the standard. Consider `void *ptr; ptr = 42;`. This clearly violates a constraint (N1570 6.5.16.1p1) -- but the standard then goes on to define the behavior in p2: "the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression".

Comment: @KeithThompson I'd argue that the "Semantics" section can only applies to code that complied with the "Constraints". In plenty of other cases the Semantics don't even make sense for code that didn't comply with the constraints, e.g. `++1;`.

Comment: @M.M: Again, I *like* that argument, but I can't derive it from the wording of the standard.

Comment: Then why does ISO/IEC 9899:1999 say _If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint is violated, the
behavior is undefined_ instead of _If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement, the
behavior is undefined_? It doesn't contradict your statement, but if constraint violations were UB, the standard is wasting words.

Answer (score 0):

As a real-world scenario where a program with a constraint violation could cause
Undefined Behavior, consider a build system which doesn't erase output files
unless/until it has something to replace them with.  When fed a valid program
it creates an executable file with a certain name, and when fed an invalid
program it leaves the old file unmodified.  Since the source text that were used to generate the leftover executable may bear no relation to the current source text, the behavior of the executable may be arbitrarily different from anything that's in the current source file.

Ideally an implementation would try to prevent accidental execution of such left-over code, but if a C compiler is just a small portion of a larger build system the compiler might not have control over such issues, and I doubt that the authors of the Standard wanted to say that build systems that didn't let a compiler delete or invalidate an executable (that it might know nothing about) should be unable to host conforming C implementations.